# Python Comprehension - Importing & Dunder Methods

Tags: python

Python Double-Underscore methods are hiding everywhere and behind everything in Python! I am curious about how this is specifically working with the interpreter.

```
import some_module as sm
```

From my current understanding:

- Import searches for requested module
- It binds result to the local assignment (if given)
- It utilizes the `__init__.py` . . . ???

There seems to be something going on that is larger than my scope of understanding. I understand we use `__init__()` for class initialization. It is functioning as a constructor for our class.
I do not understand how calling import is then utilizing the `__init__.py`.

- What exactly is happening when we run `import`?
- How is `__init__.py` different from other dunder methods?
- Can we manipulate this dunder method (if we really wanted to?)

Comment: The [`importlib` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) describes in gory detail how the import mechanism works.

Comment: `__init__.py` doesn't actually have anything to do with imports themselves; rather, it's a file used to define a package. (A package is not just a directory that contains other `.py` files; it is a module itself, though often one that doesn't contain anything *other* than other modules.) It has *nothing* to do with the `__Init__` method classes use to initialize instances of the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`import some_module` is going to look for one of two things. It's either going to look for a `some_module.py` in the search path or a `some_module/__init__.py`. Only one of those should exist. The *only* thing `__init__.py` means when it comes to modules is "this is the module that represents this folder". So consider this folder structure.

```
foo/
  __init__.py
  module1.py
bar.py
```

Then the three modules available are `foo` (which corresponds to `foo/__init__.py`), `foo.module1` (which corresponds to `foo/module1.py`), and `bar` (which corresponds to `bar.py`). By convention, `foo/__init__.py` will usually import important names from `module1.py` and reexport some of them for convenience, but this is by no means a requirement.